# How do I translate month names in post metadata?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate the month names as underlined in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLPQ3.png), without [changing the entire WP backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71RJD.png) as well, as I require the backend to remain English.

I managed to translate the default strings via's [Astra's Default String page](https://wpastra.com/docs/astra-default-strings/), but they don't provide strings for the month names.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution, if you want the frontend to be a different language than the backend, is to change the site language under Settings > General (Spanish for example) and then change your user account's language by going to Users > Your Profile and changing the Language setting to English.

In addition, you can add this code to `functions.php` to make sure the language is English for you (or any other administrator) on the frontend. You could tweak the logic if you don't want it to apply to all administrators.

```
/**
 * Sets the locale to English on the frontend if the current user is an administrator.
 *
 * @param string $locale The locale ID.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function sx372871_set_administrator_locale( $locale ) {
    // If the current user is an admin, make sure locale is set to English.
    if ( current_user_can('administrator') && ! is_admin()  ) {
        return 'en_US';
    }

    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'sx372871_set_administrator_locale' );
```

Comment: Snap, unfortunately this then changes the language of some plugins that I also require to be in English (Elementor).

Comment: @QQQ Okay, I added some code to my answer that should set the language to English for administrators. Let me know if this doesn't work for you because I have a couple of other possible solutions.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it's not overwriting neither Elementor's editor nor WP backend.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will translate month names from English to Spanish on the frontend:

```
/**
 * Translates month names on the frontend of the site.
 */
function sx372871_translate_month_names( $translated_text ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $translated_text;
    }

    $months = array(
        'january'   => 'Enero',
        'february'  => 'Febrero',
        'march'     => 'Marzo',
        'april'     => 'Abril',
        'may'       => 'Mayo',
        'june'      => 'Junio',
        'july'      => 'Julio',
        'august'    => 'Agosto',
        'september' => 'Septiembre',
        'october'   => 'Octubre',
        'november'  => 'Noviembre',
        'december'  => 'Diciembre',
    );

    if ( array_key_exists( strtolower( $translated_text ), $months ) ) {
        return $months[strtolower($translated_text)];
    }

    return $translated_text;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'sx372871_translate_month_names' );
```

Comment: I was sure this would work, but for some reason it's still not returning the translated names. I'm doing this on a staging site, cache wouldn't be the issue. I'm a bit lost at this point.